# Can CPU clock increase the performance of my program?

Tags: cpu

I want to improve the speed of my program, I have already done multi threading with parallel omp and I was wondering if I can also improve performance by increasing cpu clock speed?

I did some research and I saw that the clock speed increases the number of instructions per second, does that also mean that my program will run faster?

Comment: Sure it would make it work faster. If you have a tiny `Hello World` Programm you will not notice any changes, only if your application runs heavy.

Answer (score 0):

As in most cases, the correct answer is: It depends...

The speed your program runs with, is of course influenced by the clock speed. But it may not be the limiting factor.

There are lot's of other resources (File I/O, Network I/O, Thread synchronization, inter-process communication, Graphic/Video calculation) that may have a much more severe impact on your program speed.

It's hard to tell without more specific information if increasing the cpu clock speed would actually increase your program speed. E.g. if you are waiting for your HDD all the time, a faster CPU will not increase performance significantly.